# whats wrong with this simple snippet (parsing string into array)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Assuming element with id 'id2' is a textarea with the following entries:

a@123.com, b@123.com, c@123.com

When I run this, I am getting values 0, 1 and 2 - why?

```
jQuery('#myid').submit(function() {
    var temp = jQuery('#id2').serializeArray();
    var email_arr = temp[0].value.split(',');
    for (e in email_arr)
        alert(e);
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Try `alert(temp)`ing, and see what you get :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `for ... in` iterates keys, not values, so use `alert(email_arr[e])` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Because `e` contains the key of the object.  To get the value, use `email_arr[e]`.

Really, it's not wise to use `for...in` to iterate Arrays because it iterates, not just the items in the collection, but all the members of the Array including custom properties and methods.  So, as soon as someone extends `Array`, you will get unexpected results in your `for...in` loop.  For example, if you are using IE7 and you want to use `Array.forEach()` you'll have to extend `Array` as [recommended by MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/array/foreach#Compatibility).  With `Array` extended, now each Array you create will have an extra property that will show up as you iterate using `for...in`.

Instead, use `Array.forEach()`.  It's solves all kinds of problems that can crop up when looping through Arrays.  This does what you are trying to do:

```
email_arr.forEach(function(email, index, list)
{
    alert(email);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, in javascript, for ... in ... loop are not working the same way as in python.
Your e variable is actually looping on the "index" (keys) of your array.

You should get the desired result by looking at email_arr[e].

Comment: I wouldn't say that it is unfortunate, it's a simple way to get both the key and the value within the loop.

Comment: well. I would. :D
That's counterintuitive, because it does not match natural language.